# Network Related Terms

Tags: networking

All the networking geeks out there , can somebody please explain

What is:

- DNS Server
- Subnet Mask
- Default Gateway

Comment: Please *don't* use signatures or taglines in your posts. - http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: not an answer but www.wikipedia.com is good for all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS Server = Domain name server, it is where host names of websites or domains are connected to the ip address of the servers/networks.

Subnet Mask = subnet masks can be best explained reading [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork).

Default Gateway = is the ip address where your computer sends packets of information/ gets its connection. Generally the router you are connected to.

Comment: Probably a little technical for somebody who needs to ask the question, but you've got my up vote.